# Typewriter effect layout not inline

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, inline

```js
<div className= "HomePage-typewriter">
  I do{'\u00A0'}
  <Typewriter
    options={{
      strings: [
        '<span> this </span>',
        '<span> that </span>',
        '<span> this </span>',
      ],
      autoStart: true,
      loop: true,
      deleteSpeed: 20,
      delay: 55,
      pauseFor: 50
    }}
  />
</div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```css
.HomePage-typewriter {
  display: inline;
  text-align: left;
}
```

I want all of the text to be on the same line if possible, but, if not, then I want the line break to happen between "I do" and the typewriter text instead of making "I do" display on two lines. Like this:

[image]

I am running into trouble when I use `display: flex` instead of `display: inline`, getting a line-break in "I do" like this:

[image]

Comment: You are not closing this array  `strings: ['<span> this </span>',
                  '<span> that </span>',
                  '<span> this </span>',`

Comment: True, it was a typo in the actual question. Fixed

Comment: Great. proper indenting the code can help us in avoiding these mistakes.

Comment: You say you want the text to be on the same line, but what should happen if it doesn't fit on one line?

Comment: It's the typewriter effect that should go on the new line, not the "I do"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get better control over the line breaks by setting the `flex-wrap` attribute to `wrap` so that elements wrap to the next line before breaking lines within themselves (in other words, an element will move to the next line instead of breaking itself into multiple lines if it can).

You might also consider removing that non-breaking space and control spacing with margins on the children instead.

Here's an example with a few different container widths to show how line-breaking works:

```css
.container {
    width: 6rem;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.container.wide {
    width: 9rem;
}

.container.narrow {
    width: 3rem;
}

.container > *:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: .2rem;
}

.container span:nth-child(2) {
    color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="container wide">
  <span>First phrase</span>
  <span>Second</span>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span>First phrase</span>
  <span>Second</span>
</div>

<div class="container narrow">
  <span>First phrase</span>
  <span>Second</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<div className= "HomePage-typewriter">
  I do{'\u00A0'}
  <Typewriter class="Provide_Class Name"
      strings: [
        '<span> this </span>',
        '<span> that </span>',
        '<span> this </span>',
      ],
      autoStart: true,
      loop: true,
      deleteSpeed: 20,
      delay: 55,
      pauseFor: 50
    }}
  />
</div>
```

Your code is perfect but. I add correction on it provide class Name

```
TypeWriter start-tag
```

and then add CSS  `display: contents;`  it works perfectly